# Como tratar uma base de endereços

Tags: python

Tenho uma base de dados onde o CPF é a PK e há informações de endereço (como CEP, logradouro, número, etc). Gostaria de encontrar pessoas que moram na mesma residência, comparando logradouro e número. Entretanto, existem situações em que os nomes do logradouros foram inputados de maneira parecida, mas não igual. Exemplo: "Avenida Paulista" e "Av. Paulista". Isso dificulta o tratamento da base. Alguém teria alguma sugestão para ajudar?
Desde já, agradeço!! =)

Comment: Um dos campos no banco de dados é o CEP? Se tiver, posso sugerir uma resposta utilizando [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy). Outra opção é: se você puder alterar o banco de dados, pode procurar todas as ocorrências de ["Avenida","Av.",...] e trocar pelo que achar melhor. O mesmo para ["Rua","R.",...].

Comment: O que vc esta usando? Python puro? Nenhum framework?

Answer (score 1):

Caso você tenha o Pandas instalado (Pandas é uma biblioteca de banco de dados escrita e compatível com o Python), você pode fazer isso com o seguinte código:

```
import pandas as pd


Dicionario_BancoDeDados = {'123.456.789-10' : {'CEP': '11.111-000', 'Logradouro': 'Av. Paulista', 'Numero': 99},
                           '123.456.789-11' : {'CEP': '11.111-001', 'Logradouro': 'Av. Paulista', 'Numero': 99},
                           '123.456.789-12' : {'CEP': '11.111-002', 'Logradouro': 'Av. Distante', 'Numero': 99}}


BancoDeDados = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Dicionario_BancoDeDados).T     # .T é a operação de transposição


BancoDeDados
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podes encontrar pessoas que moram na mesma residência executando:

```
VizinhosDePredio = BancoDeDados[BancoDeDados.duplicated(['Logradouro', 'Numero'], keep=False) == True]

VizinhosDePredio
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A fim de contornar dubiedades em nomes de logradouro, sugiro que o faça antes de fazer a busca por vizinhos. Mostro-lhe abaixo uma implementação tal:

```
Dicionario_BancoDeDados = {'123.456.789-10' : {'CEP': '11.111-000', 'Logradouro': 'Av. Paulista',     'Numero': 99},
                           '123.456.789-11' : {'CEP': '11.111-001', 'Logradouro': 'Avenida Paulista', 'Numero': 99},
                           '123.456.789-12' : {'CEP': '11.111-002', 'Logradouro': 'Av. Distante',     'Numero': 99}}


BancoDeDados = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Dicionario_BancoDeDados).T



def AbreviarLogradouro(Logradouro):

    Logradouro = Logradouro.replace('Avenida', 'Av.')
    Logradouro = Logradouro.replace('Rua', 'R.' )

    return Logradouro



BancoDeDados['Logradouro'] = BancoDeDados['Logradouro'].map(lambda x: AbreviarLogradouro(x))

BancoDeDados
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: (desconsiderar a incoerência de CEPs diferentes para endereços iguais :)

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o que você precisa é utilizar o comando `LIKE` em sua consulta sql. Como existem diferentes formas para o texto inserido na coluna de logradouro logradouro, você poderia fazer uso do comando citado acima, segue exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT *campo1, campo2...*, FROM *table* WHERE UPPER(logradouro) LIKE UPPER ('%Av%paulista%')
```

Ou

```
SELECT *campo1, campo2...*, FROM *table* WHERE LOWER(logradouro) LIKE LOWER('%Av%paulista%')
```